# How to save OpenModelica Simulation results

Tags: openmodelica

I am using OpenModelica in my work.
How do I save OpenModelica simulations results?

Answer (score 2):

It depends. If you are using OMEdit you can find the result in the working directory of OMEdit

[image]

If you want to save your model as an executable via OpenModelica-scripting you can use mos scripts in the following way:

```
setCommandLineOptions({"-d=execstat"});
loadFile("model.mo");getErrorString();
buildModel(model); getErrorString();
```

To run the executable for two seconds, here with the IDA solver:

```
"./model -override=stopTime=2.0 -s=ida", "log.log"
```

The resulting simulation will be saved in your working directory with this approach.

Or you can write the following mos script:

```
loadFile("HelloWorld.mo");getErrorString();
simulate(HelloWorld);getErrorString();
```

with the following Modelica model:

```
model HelloWorld
  Real x( start = 1, fixed = true );
  parameter Real a = 1;
equation
  der(x) = - a * x;
end HelloWorld;
```

The output will be as follows:

true

```
""
record SimulationResult
    resultFile = "/mnt/c/<Path>/HelloWorld_res.mat",
    simulationOptions = "startTime = 0.0, stopTime = 1.0, numberOfIntervals = 500, tolerance = 1e-06, method = 'dassl', fileNamePrefix = 'HelloWorld', options = '', outputFormat = 'mat', variableFilter = '.*', cflags = '', simflags = ''",
    messages = "LOG_SUCCESS       | info    | The initialization finished successfully without homotopy method.
LOG_SUCCESS       | info    | The simulation finished successfully.
",
    timeFrontend = 0.007985600000000001,
    timeBackend = 0.0152096,
    timeSimCode = 0.0033462,
    timeTemplates = 0.09332140000000001,
    timeCompile = 1.7051749,
    timeSimulation = 0.0506992,
    timeTotal = 1.8771728
end SimulationResult;
```

The result will then be available in `HelloWorld_res.mat` in your working directory